# Calculating an XPath of a given element in CasperJS

Tags: javascript, xml, xpath, casperjs

I am trying to use the [getElementXPath function from Firebug](https://github.com/firebug/firebug/blob/master/extension/content/firebug/lib/xpath.js) to work in CasperJS but I can't seem to find the right place to call it for it to work.  Here is what I have so far and it only works for objects that have an "id" tag already, but that isn't much help because I am using the XPath in place of an id (Most objects do not have ids)

```js
casper.then(function () {
    var Element = this.evaluate(function(){
        var elm = document.querySelector('[class="h4"]');
        return getElementXPath(elm); //Set 1
        //return elm; //Set 2
    });

    console.log('xpath: '+ Element); //Set 1
    //console.log('xpath: '+ getElementXPath(Element)); //Set 2
});
```

Set 1 always outputs "xpath: null"

Set 2 only outputs the correct path if the element already has an "id" tag. "xpath: //*[id="button"]"

Set 2 will otherwise output the last tag i.e. "xpath: /a" or "xpath: /span"

Here is the getElementXPath function from Firebug which I just pasted at the top of my JS file.

```js
function getElementXPath(element)
{
    if (element && element.id)
        return '//*[@id="' + element.id + '"]';
    else
        return getElementTreeXPath(element);
};

function getElementTreeXPath(element)
{
    var paths = [];
    // Use nodeName (instead of localName) so namespace prefix is included (if any).
    for (; element && element.nodeType == Node.ELEMENT_NODE; element = element.parentNode)
    {
        var index = 0;
        var hasFollowingSiblings = false;
        for (var sibling = element.previousSibling; sibling; sibling = sibling.previousSibling)
        {
            // Ignore document type declaration.
            if (sibling.nodeType == Node.DOCUMENT_TYPE_NODE)
                continue;
            if (sibling.nodeName == element.nodeName)
                ++index;
        }

        for (var sibling = element.nextSibling; sibling && !hasFollowingSiblings;
            sibling = sibling.nextSibling)
        {
            if (sibling.nodeName == element.nodeName)
                hasFollowingSiblings = true;
        }
        var tagName = (element.prefix ? element.prefix + ":" : "") + element.localName;
        var pathIndex = (index || hasFollowingSiblings ? "[" + (index + 1) + "]" : "");
        paths.splice(0, 0, tagName + pathIndex);
    }
    return paths.length ? "/" + paths.join("/") : null;
};
```

Comment: https://github.com/firebug/firebug/blob/master/extension/content/firebug/lib/xpath.js

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you listen to the `"page.error"` event, then you see something like

> Error: ReferenceError: Can't find variable: getElementXPath

This has something to do with how you included that code in the page. The following complete script works for me:

```js
var casper = require('casper').create();

// http://docs.casperjs.org/en/latest/events-filters.html#page-error
casper.on("page.error", function(msg, trace) {
    this.echo("Error: " + msg);
    // maybe make it a little fancier with the code from the PhantomJS equivalent
});

casper.start('http://example.com');

casper.then(function() {               
    this.evaluate(function(){
        window.getElementXPath = function(element)
        {
            if (element && element.id)
                return '//*[@id="' + element.id + '"]';
            else
                return getElementTreeXPath(element);
        };

        function getElementTreeXPath(element)
        {
            var paths = [];
            // Use nodeName (instead of localName) so namespace prefix is included (if any).
            for (; element && element.nodeType == Node.ELEMENT_NODE; element = element.parentNode)
            {
                var index = 0;
                var hasFollowingSiblings = false;
                for (var sibling = element.previousSibling; sibling; sibling = sibling.previousSibling)
                {
                    // Ignore document type declaration.
                    if (sibling.nodeType == Node.DOCUMENT_TYPE_NODE)
                        continue;
                    if (sibling.nodeName == element.nodeName)
                        ++index;
                }

                for (var sibling = element.nextSibling; sibling && !hasFollowingSiblings;
                    sibling = sibling.nextSibling)
                {
                    if (sibling.nodeName == element.nodeName)
                        hasFollowingSiblings = true;
                }
                var tagName = (element.prefix ? element.prefix + ":" : "") + element.localName;
                var pathIndex = (index || hasFollowingSiblings ? "[" + (index + 1) + "]" : "");
                paths.splice(0, 0, tagName + pathIndex);
            }
            return paths.length ? "/" + paths.join("/") : null;
        };
    });

    this.echo(this.evaluate(function(){
        return getElementXPath(document.querySelector("a"));
    }));
});

casper.run();
```

Output:

```
/html/body/div/p[2]/a
```

The trick is to make `getElementXPath` available in the global scope in the page context. This can be easily accomplished by setting the variable on `window.getElementXPath`.

Comment: Why does jquery $("a:contains('text')") not work inplace of document.querySelector("a") for the input parameter?

Comment: The output of `$("a:contains('text')")` is a jQuery collection and not an element. You would need to check that the collection contains at least one element `var al = $("a:contains('text')"); if (al.length > 0) { ... }` and then retrieve the element `al[0]`.